# Getting 404 Error when I start my EXT JS App in DJANGO

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, portal, django-1.5

I want to integrate EXT JS's Portal Example in my application so I downloaded that from

`http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/community/extjs4-mvc-portal/`

When I try it in Java.. it runs perfectly fine.. but when I run it in Django, where my 
application is built on.. it shows me this error :

```
"GET /designLayout/app/view/Viewport.js?_dc=1363392859943 HTTP/1.1" 404 3384
```

All the other `GET` requests are runnings well, for example :

```
 "GET /static/extjs/src/layout/container/Form.js?_dc=1363392859942 HTTP/1.1" 200 4252
```

I have no idea why it is looking for Viewport.js?_dc=1363392859943 when `autoCreateViewport: true` is defined in app.js according to the example I downloaded.

How should I go by configuring the 'app' in django? Right now all my files are in `static` folder so that Django picks it up.

Please guide me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you still need to configure a Viewport.js even if you defined autoCreateViewport - this just autowires the Ext.create() of the viewport so you don't have to code that in your launch.

just make sure your server side url's are the same or ajusted to your django environment.

Comment: Sorry but I am a noob in Django.. I have simply copy pasted the whole code.. in my django project..

This is what I get..
`"GET /designLayout/app/view/Viewport.js?_dc=1363625066250 HTTP/1.1" 404 3384`

So if you don't mind could you please tell me how should I configure that in my urls?
Right now I am trying something like this : 

`#url(r'^designLayout/app/view/$', '/designlayout/static/app/view/Viewport.js'),`

If Django is searching for the GET Url.. what should be my url? and what should the view parameter be in the url? 
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

you need add

```
appFolder: 'static/app',
```

to app.js like

```
Ext.application({
name: 'ExtMVC',
appFolder: 'static/app',
```

then you request will be

```
GET /static/app/view/Viewport.js?_dc=1399625376954 HTTP/1.1" 200 1248
```

i am sucess run this Example !